# ExtJS/PHP/MySQL: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, alert

I'm trying to figure out why the $sql echo statement below is throwing this error in JavaScript.  Is it from the $sql assignment statement?  Why would that be?  I'm just running through some book examples that were written in PHP.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["exec"]) && $_POST["exec"] == "1") {
    $url = "127.0.0.1";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $db = "book1";

$message = "1";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

    $link = mysql_connect($url, $user, $pass) or die("cannot connect.");
    $sdb = mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die("faild select db");

$message = "2";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

    $sql = implode("\n", array(
        "SELECT",
        "    COUNT(id) as auth,",
        "    book1.users.email,",
        "    book1.users.firstname,",
        "    book1.users.lastname",
        "FROM",
        "    book1.users",
        "WHERE",
        "    book1.users.email = 'k'",
        "AND",
        "    book1.users.passwd = SHA1(MD5('k'))",
        "AND",
        "    book1.users.status = 1;"
    ));


echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$sql');</script>";


    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die("faild query<hr/>SQL:" . $sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $auth = $row["auth"];
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link) or die("faild disconnect");
    if ($auth == "1") {
        $_SESSION["USERINFO"] = array(
            "email" => $row["email"],
            "firstname" => $row["firstname"],
            "lastname" => $row["lastname"]
        );
        header("Location: ./index.php");
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
E-Mail:<input type="text" name="email" value=""/><br/>
Password:<input type=password" name="passwd" value="" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input type="hidden" name="exec" value="1"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

This is what the code used to look like, but throws the same error in the browser Console window.

```
$sql = implode("\n", array(
    "SELECT",
    "    COUNT(id) as auth,",
    "    users.email,",
    "    users.firstname,",
    "    users.lastname",
    "FROM",
    "    users",
    "WHERE",
    "    users.email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'",
    "AND",
    "    users.passwd = SHA1(MD5('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwd']) . "'))",
    "AND",
    "    users.status = 1;"
));
```

Comment: First try to set `$sql = 'test';` to check if it's the original `$sql` generating the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the author forgot the quote before the value ("password") of the type attribute in the input field.  I may be the only one who ever tried this example with real code for the book "Ext JS Data-driven Application Design" that was published on packtpub.com.  That makes me feel special.

I created a schema (PHP $db variable - MySQL schema is analogous to a database) called "book1", and changed the database credentials to root/root in the code to match the setup of MySQL I installed on Windows.  And then I had to add a user to the "users" table with a status of 1 to make things work.

Maybe writing scripts on MySQL for the version (6.3) I used was different, but the syntax also kept failing when creating the table.  I had to ignore all lines except the CREATE statement.  I also excluded the code starting with "ENGINE".

**original code from Chapter 1:**

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

**New code:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Maybe consider a different book to learn from. You should not use any book which is still using `mysql_*` functions, as these have been deprecated for several years.